# A way to get string between tokens in code

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have something like this

```
fragment COMMENT_TEXT : ~(')')* ;
COMMENT : '(' COMMENT_TEXT ')' ;
SLASH_COMMENT : '//' COMMENT_TEXT '//' ;
comment : COMMENT | SLASH_COMMENT ;
```

And want to get `COMMENT_TEXT` string in-code. It seems like some simple task but I just stuck in it for a while now. Here is a part of the listener:

```
public override void ExitComment(P.CommentContext context)
{
    var cb = new CommentBlock();
    cb.OriginalText = context.GetText();
    _currentBlock = cb;
}
```

`OriginalText` is a comment with braces. How do I get `COMMENT_TEXT` itself?
Pls provide a link to the relevant article to solve this, not the Ultimate tutorial or the Reference manual itself.

For example, for input like this:

```
(testCommentText123)
```

I want to get

```
CommentBlock.OriginalText == "testCommentText123"
```

Comment: read the second line after :, will it help?

Comment: even your questions also unclear

Comment: @viveknuna Is it better with the example now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific way to access the individual parts of a token in ANTLR. You'll just have to take apart the string yourself. You could either do that using a regular expression or by checking the token type (to see whether it's a slash or parentheses comment) and then using `Substring` to remove the first and last 2 or 1 (depending on the type of comment) characters.

PS: Your `SLASH_COMMENT` rule will match everything from the first `//` in your file up to the last `//`. That's probably not what you want.